UML Association: Are "navigableOwnedEnd" and "ownedEnd" the same?
Please refer to the following diagram which is shown in the UML 2.5.1 specification at section 11.5.2 on page 241 of the PDF file:

What is the difference here? navigableOwnedEnd subsets ownedEnd, and due to the dot notation, both are navigable by default. The descriptions on page 261 are basically the same.

Good question. One would mean that "owned" implies "navigable"

These are two different concepts, as UML specs state page 202:

Aggregation type, navigability, and end ownership are separate concepts, each with their own explicit notation.

End ownership is a structural characteristic whereas navigability is a runtime promise. See this OMG article for an in-depth analysis.
While navigability is assumed with the dot notation, UML specs explicitly allow for a combination of navigability and dot notation, page 202:

The dot may be used in combination with the other graphic line-path notations for Properties of Associations and Association ends. These include aggregation type and navigability.


Thank you (I already knew about that article in the link). I think the confusion here arises from the diagram depicting Association and its relations to Property on the metamodel level and not at the modeling level. In the meantime, I found this in section 6.4.2: "By definition, all class-owned association ends are navigable. By convention, all association-owned ends in the metamodel are NOT navigable." So although the dot notation makes sense on the metamodel level, it doesn't really depict what is going on at the modeling level. But maybe I am wrong about this?

It once again appears that legacy has a long lastinng memory and helps only to bring up confusion (must I remind the hollow diamond?).

@RobertHairgrove I understand the chapter 6 to apply to the metamodel and I would not transpose it the UML modeling. Indeed, there is no such claim in the section about classes, associations and properties. By the way, interestingly the metamodel itself combines the dot notation with navigability notation, which tends to suggest that there is not a consensus between all the authors.

No, they are not the same. An Property can be owned by the Association or by the Class. If it is owned by the Class it is automatically navigable. If it is owned by the Association it is only navigable if it is a also a navigableOwnedEnd.
That means the concrete syntax of the navigability arrow has two mappings to the abstract syntax.

Still a confusing concept, though.
